# Winter is here, what type of trainer should I get?

Tags: trainer, ant+

Well, it started raining today and I'm not much of a road cycling in the rain type of guy. Given that this weather will last for a few months, I was wondering what type of trainer should I get. I would like something that works with my Garmin Edge 520. My rear tire cannot fit the little rubber Garmin tracker thingy, so should I try to get an Ant+ trainer? Do those even exist? If not, what are some decent recommendations that won't break the bank? Are there certain features I should look for?

Comment: Product recommendations are generally off-topic here because the answers go out of date so fast. If you can edit it into "what features should I look for" you might get away with it, but even that's likely to be opinion-based and more suitable for one of the biking forums.

Comment: That's fair @Mσᶎ. I've edited my post per your recommendation. Thanks.

Comment: well you basically have a choice of a turbo trainer or rollers, but each gives you something different in terms of training. It sounds like you're talking about a turbo, in which case you should see what is available for your budget....bearing in mind you can pay thousands for whizz-bang virtual reality machines

Comment: Rule 5 applies.

Comment: What do you mean "cannot fit the little rubber Garmin tracker thing"? There are plenty of little cycling computers you can just bolt to your bike (some with ant+) to use on any trainer.

Comment: @Batman - the little Garmin sensor is too wide for my back tire, and sits on the front. If I were to use a trainer or roller, it would not record my speed. I would like to record my workouts and use my Garmin for it.

Comment: If you're using rollers, your speed measurement stuff should work as is -- both wheels turn on rollers.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have a wheel sensor on the bike that connects to your gps?
like this: [here](https://buy.garmin.com/en-US/US/shop-by-accessories/fitness-sensors/bike-speed-sensor-and-cadence-sensor/prod146897.html)

I use this [one](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000BFNOT8) for my garmin 405. With either of these set ups you can use whatever you like best for training. Go to your LBS (local bike shop) and ask to try their trainers (mag or fluid) and their rollers. I personally use rollers since it is less wear and tear on just the rear wheel. Though it does take a bit to get used to it before you can ride it without fear of crashing down! If your in the states then the rollers I would get are [Nashbars reduced radius rollers](http://www.nashbar.com/bikes/Product_10053_10052_173072_-1___). I have used mine for a few seasons and they are very nice!

Comment: I have the little sensor you first linked. It sits on my front tire as the back tire is too narrow for it. It looks like rollers is the right route for me given the  more 'on the road' experience. I was looking at this Nashbar roller (http://www.nashbar.com/bikes/Product_10053_10052_534675_-1___) actually. Are they easy to get used to. Would you be able to watch a TV show or something, or do you have to spend a lot of time concentrating?

Comment: Probably a week or two of practice before your watching TV with them depending on how much saddle time you plan on getting. It took about a week of 2 hour sessions for me to watch anything but my front wheel!

Comment: Any pro-tips on staying stable? Is it basically a mental thing?

Comment: Pretty much a "getting the hang of balancing" thing. Won't take very long though it will be scary at first. First ride I put it up against a wall in case I slipped off I could then reach out. Not a great idea. I rode better when I was forced to pay attention.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be warm and dry and indoors then a trainer or rollers are probably what you want.  Rollers and resistance trainers tend to be hard on bikes and tyres, its not unusual to use the "spare" bike on a trainer.

Approximately where in the world are you?    I'm in the Southern Hemisphere, and were just coming into summer.  I managed at least 500 km/month of mostly road, but there was a bit of velodrome and a fair serving of singletrack too.

I'm guessing you're a MTB guy, possibly a downhill type and when its wet and horrible, those can be additionally dangerous.  Consider some Cross Country, or even pop on some slick tyres, lock out the suspension and hit some roads to boost your endurance.   Biking in the rain can be excellent training, just need a bit more gear and preparation.  Biking in fallen snow is magical.
Remember rule #5.

Finally, do remember that howling southerlies can also be the best tailwinds.

Comment: I am in Northern California. Given that we had a really dry year, any excess water on the road mixes with the oils and creates a bit of a hazardous environment. Additionally, all the uphills are covered with leaves and make the journey back down a bit more challenging. I'd rather just stay indoors and train.

AS for the roller note you made, if I'm going to replace the tires next season, I shouldn't have much to worry about the strain, right?

Comment: Fair call.   I'd pop a TV or computer in front of the trainer - its really boring staring at the wall while peddling.  Or set it up looking out a window.   If nothing else a radio or mp3 player will help too.

Comment: My default is audio books, but I have neglected my various TV/Movie subscriptions and I need to catch up.

Comment: @zlatty How about biking around inside google earth / streetview?   http://www.bikerumor.com/2011/01/05/hack-ride-your-bike-anywhere-in-the-world-with-google-earth/ or  http://www.livescience.com/46714-virtual-training-indoor-cycling.html   Both use  a display in front of the rider, and some kind of wheel counter that measures your forward progess, and winds you through the route.  Not sure how they handle turning, if at all.    Could be the only way I'll ride up the Col de Tentes.

Comment: That looks pretty entertaining @Criggie. I'll have to test this out once I have my setup. :)

Answer (score -1):

You need a Roller Trainer ;) my friend.
https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=roller+trainer+fail

Comment: This is very encouraging :P

Comment: Gidday and welcome to SE bicycles.  We prefer the site to be self contained, and while youtube probably won't ever go away, it is hard for the search function to index a video.  Please consider summarising your main points in text, in your answer.

Comment: Welcome to Bicycles SE. We prefer answers on this site to be self-contained. That way, the answer is still valid if the link dies. Please summarize what information is contained in the link within the body of your answer. Otherwise, it is likely to be downvoted, flagged for moderator intervention, and possibly deleted.